# User enters 2 numbers, output numbers and sums in table. Outputting, but not in table?

Tags: javascript, function, html-table

Write a program that asks a user to enter three numbers. If all three entries are numbers then output the sum of all combinations of pairs of numbers from the three entries. The code that performs the addition and outputs the result for each pair should be in a function and is called from the main function. Output the answers in an HTML table. The table and its end tag should be added to the HTML page. The table rows will be inserted with the program.

I can get the program to *mostly* work, but it's not outputting the numbers and sums as part of the table, and I'm not sure where/what I'm missing?

```
    //function to output sum of number1 and number2
    function outputSumOfnumber1Andnumber2(number1, number2) {
        var output;
        sum1and2 = number1 + number2;
        output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
        output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + sum1and2 + "</td></tr>";
    }

    function outputSumofnumber2Andnumber3(number2, number3) {
        var output;
        sum2and3 = number2 + number3;
        output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
        output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum2and3 + "</td></tr>";
    }

    function outputSumofnumber1Andnumber3(number1, number3) {
        var output;
        sum1and3 = number1 + number3;
        output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
        output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum1and3 + "</td></tr></table>";
    }

    function exercise3Part2() {
        // PART 2: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
        var number1;
        var number2;
        var number3;
        var output;
        var tableRows;

        number1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
        number2 = Number(prompt("Enter another number:"));
        number3 = Number(prompt("Enter one more number:"));

        output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');

        output.innerHTML = "<table><tr><th>Pair part 1</th><th>Pair part 2</th><th>Sum</th></tr>";

        outputSumOfnumber1Andnumber2(number1, number2);
        outputSumofnumber2Andnumber3(number2, number3);
        outputSumofnumber1Andnumber3(number1, number3);

    }
```

Attempt 2--

```
//function to output sum of numbers
function outputSumOfnumbers(number1, number2, number3, rows) {
    var output;
    var rows;

    sum1and2 = number1 + number2;
    sum2and3 = number2 + number3;
    sum1and3 = number1 + number3;
    output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
    rows = "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + sum1and2 + "</td></tr>";
    rows += "<tr><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum2and3 + "</td></tr>";
    rows += "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum1and3 + "</td></tr>";

}

function exercise3Part2() {
    // PART 2: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
    var number1;
    var number2;
    var number3;
    var myTable;
    var rows;

    myTable = document.getElementById('outputPart2');

    number1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
    number2 = Number(prompt("Enter another number:"));
    number3 = Number(prompt("Enter one more number:"));
outputSumOfnumbers(number1, number2, number3);
    myTable = document.getElementById('outputPart2');



    myTable.innerHTML += rows;

}
```

Comment: You're also not using a single function to do your sums, like the assignment says.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you messed things up, but instead of fixing this code, I prefer that you choose a better approach on table manipulation, this is definitely NOT the way you should do it.

Check this article: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/working_w_tables_using_jquery.html

I believe that you will get it right when you apply what is inside. (:

Answer (score 0):

I added an opening and closing table tag to my HTML (with an id) and used the below code:

```
//function to output sum of number1 and number2
function outputSumOfnumber1Andnumber2(number1, number2) {
    var output;
    sum1and2 = number1 + number2;
    output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + sum1and2 + "</td></tr>";
}

function outputSumofnumber2Andnumber3(number2, number3) {
    var output;
    sum2and3 = number2 + number3;
    output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number2 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum2and3 + "</td></tr>";
}

function outputSumofnumber1Andnumber3(number1, number3) {
    var output;
    sum1and3 = number1 + number3;
    output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');
    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + number1 + "</td><td>" + number3 + "</td><td>" + sum1and3 + "</td></tr></table>";
}

function exercise3Part2() {
    // PART 2: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
    var number1;
    var number2;
    var number3;
    var output;
    var tableRows;

    number1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
    number2 = Number(prompt("Enter another number:"));
    number3 = Number(prompt("Enter one more number:"));

    output = document.getElementById('outputPart2');

    output.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Pair part 1</th><th>Pair part 2</th><th>Sum</th></tr>";

    outputSumOfnumber1Andnumber2(number1, number2);
    outputSumofnumber2Andnumber3(number2, number3);
    outputSumofnumber1Andnumber3(number1, number3);

}
```